# Create question with an accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [48 hour accept own answer delay wastes other answerer's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134269/48-hour-accept-own-answer-delay-wastes-other-answerers-time)

I recently had a programming issue for which I couldn't find the answer on stack overflow.

Thankfully I found a solution on another forum so figured I'd create a question and answer to it on stack in the hope it may help others in the future searching for the specific issue.

When the question was posted the answer I provided is not marked as answer, if I try and mark as answer then I must wait two days.

Could it be made possible to post questions with accepted answers - I think it would improve the site as users who are looking at the particular tags dont waste their time viewing questions which are essentially answered just unable to be marked as.

The question referred to and a example of user whose time would have been saved can be seen here:

[Error: Live editing has been turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011995/error-live-editing-has-been-turned-off)